# How to join two tables where you only want the record with the max date from one side of the join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I am trying to write a query to return currently unfilled training requirements.

The 4 main tables involved are:

- TrainingRequirements table: Stores a CourseId and UserId. The user and course required to be completed.
- UserTraining table: Stores a CourseId, UserId, and when the training was completed.
- User table: The user who took the training.
- Course table: The course for the training taken. Stores how many months a training is valid for.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TrainingRequirements
    INNER JOIN Users on Users.Id = TrainingRequirements.UserId
    INNER JOIN Courses on Courses.Id = TrainingRequirements.CourseId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTrainings on UserTrainings .CourseId = TrainReq.CourseId 
    AND UserTrainings .UserId = TrainingRequirements.UserId
WHERE 
    Users.Active = 1 AND 
    TrainingRequirements.Active = 1 AND 
    (UserTrainings.Id is null OR 
       --covers if they never took the training at all
    GETDATE() >= DATEADD(month, Courses.MonthsValid, UserTrainings.DateCompleted)) 
       --covers if they took the training but it has expired and must be retaken
```

This almost works. It returns me instances where they never took the training (so UserTraining.Id is null because no matching record exists on the right side of the left outer join), but it also returns to me a bunch of older completed trainings that are no longer applicable.

If a training is required annually, the user training would accumulate multiple records over the years. I only want to compare it to the most recent completion, that is the highest DateCompleted per user per training, so I assume I need to use some sort of MAX() or Group By or subquery in the join, but I can't figure it out.

Sample Data:
**TrainingRequirements**

```
Id | UserId  | CourseId | active
1  | 1       |1          | 1
2  | 1       |2          | 1
3  | 1       |3          | 0 
4  | 1       |4          | 1
```

**UserTrainings**

```
Id | UserId | CourseId | DateCompleted
1  |1       |1         | 2022-10-23 12:20:11.526
2  |1       |2         | 2021-11-15 05:01:12.320
3  |1       |2         | 2020-12-11 11:11:40.320
```

**Courses**

```
Id | Name                  | MonthsValid
1  | 'Cool Training'       | 36
2  | 'Secret Training'     | 12
3  | 'Top Secret Training' | 6
4  | 'Unpopular Training'  | 12
```

In the above, Requirement 3 is not active so can be ignored, Requirement 1 has a completion on 10/23/2023 and is valid for 36 months, so it's not expired and can also be ignored. 2 and 4 should be returned. 4 was never completed, and 2 was completed but since the expiration date (date of previous completion + months valid)

**Desired Results**

```
TrainingRequirementId | UserId | CourseId | LastTaken | Expired
2                     | 1      | 2        | 11/15/2021| 11/15/2022
4                     | 1      | 4        | null      | null
```

Using my query returns an additional row because the UserTraining with ID 3 is also matched. But since that is older an older completion I want to exclude it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results in addition to your query. Descriptive text is a poor way to try and communicate data requirements.

Comment: We don't know the contents of your table, nor what you're results are supposed to look like. Please provide some sample data that illustrates your problem and then show us what you _want_ it to look like. It's very difficult to reason about SQL queries from their linguistic description alone. Having data will get you much further.

Comment: I've updated my post with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without actual data to run this against, I'm kind of fumbling in the dark (i.e. I can't verify this actually does what you want) but it *sounds* like you want to get users who need to take a course, or took it, but over *n* months ago.

To do this, you need the first row for each combination of `UserID` and `CourseID` when ordered by `DateCompleted`. The function [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a *window function* which helps with this. It adds a series of numbers (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.) over each "partition" (e.g. in your case `UserID`, `CourseId`) ordered by whatever you choose (in this case, `DateCompleted desc`) and since you order it by `DateCompleted desc` the row with the value of 1 will always be the most recenty for that partition.

You should be able to run something like this to see what that looks like:

```
select
    RID = row_number() over (partition by UserID, CourseId order by DateCompleted desc),
    CourseId,
    UserID,
    DateCompleted
from UserTrainings
```

From there, it's back to what you were doing before, except instead of joining to the actual `UserTrainings` table, you join to the `CTE` you created with the `row_number` over it, and you add the additional join predicate `where u.RID = 1` to only grab the rows out of the `CTE` where `DateCompleted` is the most recent.

Here's what I came up with. Again, without actual data, you may need to futz with this a bit, but I think this should get you on the right track.

```
;with ut as
(
    select
        RID = row_number() over (partition by UserID, CourseId order by DateCompleted desc),
        CourseId,
        UserID,
        DateCompleted
    from UserTrainings
)
select *
from TrainingRequirements tr
inner join users u
    on tr.UserID = u.UserID
inner join courses c
    on tr.CourseId = c.CourseID
left outer join ut u
    on r.CourseId = u.CourseId
        and r.UserID = u.UserId
        and u.RID = 1 -- This gets the most recent record for each user/course in UserTrainings, sorted by DateCompleted
where u.CourseID is null -- they haven't taken it
    or ut.DateCompleted < dateadd(month, r.MonthsValid, getdate())
```

Comment: Yes, this works, the with ut ... and row_number() over (partition)... and then updating the orignal query with ut.RID = 1. Didn't know such a function existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If a training is required annually, the user training would accumulate multiple records over the years. I only want to compare it to the most recent completion,

Generally I would recommend a `row_number()` windowing function approach here (and there's already another answer that does this).

But if you just want to show the most recent date (or null) of an annual required training, you can include a requirement in the ON clause for the join to only use records within the last year:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTrainings on ... AND UserTrainings.DateCompleted > DATEADD(year, -1, get_date())
```

You could perhaps still find some duplicates, but I don't think many people do those required trainings any more often than they absolutely have to

This would also show a `NULL` instead of an old date for people who completed a training more than a year ago, but it sounds like that might actually be desirable.

I further noticed this condition in the WHERE clause:

```
 GETDATE() >= DATEADD(month, Courses.MonthsValid, UserTrainings.DateCompleted))
```

We could, instead, move this to the ON condition for the JOIN and perhaps get an even better results. But if we do (or even if we don't!) we should modify it to better work with indexes (be **sargable**):

```
DATEAD(month, -Courses.MonthsValid, GETDATE()) >= UserTrainings.DateCompleted
```

This version of the expression has the *same meaning*, but can -- without any exaggeration -- be multiple orders of magnitude faster! Really.

Comment: Thank you, why is that last expression much faster than the original?

Comment: @SventoryMang When you use the `DATEADD()` function on the `DateCompleted`, the result no longer matches the value stored in any indexes. It completely prevents their use, and indexing cuts straight to the core of database performance. This version leaves `DateCompleted` unaltered, and so indexes can still be used.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation.